# How to mock private static final field

Tags: java, mocking

I have class which I need test:

```
class MyClass {
    private final static MyOtherClass myOtherClass = OtherClassFactory.get();
    public void doSomething() {}
}
```

How to mock `myOtherClass` in unit test?

Comment: Whch mocking framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Deencapsulation.setField` method from the JMockit mocking library; it supports setting of `final` fields as well (as long as the field is not initialized to a compile-time constant, which is not the case here).